# Realm Android with relationships

Tags: java, android, realm

I have two `RealmObject` one is   `PinCode`   and another is Address. In   `Pincode`   I am storing some predefined data like `"100233,123456,423233"` etc. I am also storing Address which has `Pincode` in it like `

```
class Address extends  RealmObject
{ 
String address;
PinCode pincode;
```

`

Now If I add an address with `PinCode` "757041", will this pincode be added to `PinCode` predefined data that I have created earlier??

Comment: why don't you try it out and see what happens

Comment: @TimCastelijns I am still in initial phase..I will soon do it myself. But I thought someone might have the answer of my query prior to trying it by myself..

Comment: Why isn't `PinCode` just a string field??

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It could be anything...As an example i hv set it like this

Comment: I stand by my question.

Answer (score 0):

Realm works like an object graph, so if you multiple `PinCode` references, they will only point to the same object if you did that explicitly. It doesn't happen by itself.

If you want multiple objects to reference another one, it is pretty common to give that object a primary key so it is easy to lookup and find:

```
public class Address extends RealmObject {
  public PinCode pinCode;
  public String address;
}

public class PinCode {
  @PrimaryKey public String id = UUID.getRandom().toString();
  public String code;
}

PinCode p = realm.where(PinCode.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();

// These two addresses will point to the same object
realm.createObject(Address.class).pinCode = p;
realm.createObject(Address.class).pinCode = p;
```